# How to apply code to dataframe by condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(concordance)
Year <- c(2016,2016,2017,2019,2020,2020,2020,2013,2010,2010)
Pf <- c("HS4","HS4","HS4","HS5","HS5","HS5","HS5","HS4","HS3","HS3")
Code <- c("391890","440929","851660","732399","720839","050510","830241","321590","010210","010210")
Slen <- c("6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6")
df <-  data.frame(Year,Pf,Code,Slen)
```

'Pf' column contains 3 different types of rows: "HS3", "HS4" and "HS5". I want to perform a vectorized operation and apply [concord()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/concordance/versions/2.0.0) function to the 'Code' column", however in order to do that, 'Pf' must be Unique that's why before I sebset datarames where 'Pf' column is unique

```
# Subset data where Pf column is unique
df.H5 <- subset(df, Pf == "HS5")
df.H4  <- subset(df, Pf == "HS4")
df.H3  <- subset(df, Pf == "HS3")
```

Now I apply a function to each dataframe. Here `concord()` function applies to 'Code' column and converts these characters to different ones. However, if destination (argument) and values in 'Pf' column are the same it does not work, for instance, if Pf="HS3" (in df) and destination = "HS3", the code does not run, that's why I don't apply code to df.H3

```
# Apply function to df.H5
df.H5<- df.H5 %>% 
  group_by(Pf, Slen) %>%
  mutate(
    Code2 = concord(Code, origin = unique(Pf), dest.digit = unique(Slen), destination = "HS3", all = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# Apply function to df.H4
df.H4<- df.H4 %>% 
  group_by(Pf, Slen) %>%
  mutate(
    Code2 = concord(Code, origin = unique(Pf), dest.digit = unique(Slen), destination = "HS3", all = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

#add column todf.H3 in order to merge these 3 tafarames
df.H3$Code2 <- df.H3$Code

#merge
df2 <- rbind(df.H4, df.H5, df.H3)
```

My goal is to somehow automate the process. For instance, if destination = "HS3", the code applies whole data without pre-subsetting and if destination (argument) and rows in Pf match each other, the code does not apply to it and just copy-paste values from 'Code' to generated 'Code2' column in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the logic in a function and use it in a `by` approach which splits data and applies functions. In the function you could do a case handling where supposedly `P == 'HS3'` should not be processed. Finally `unsplit`.

```
cf <- \(x) {
  Code2 <- if (!any(x$Pf == 'HS3')) {
    concordance::concord(x$Code, x$Pf[1], x$Slen[1], 
                         destination="HS3", all=FALSE)
  } else {
    x$Code
  }
  cbind(x, Code2)
}

by(df, df$Pf, cf) |>
  unsplit(df$Pf)
#    Year  Pf   Code Slen  Code2
# 1  2016 HS4 391890    6 391890
# 2  2016 HS4 440929    6 440929
# 3  2017 HS4 851660    6 851660
# 4  2019 HS5 732399    6 732399
# 5  2020 HS5 720839    6 720839
# 6  2020 HS5 050510    6 050510
# 7  2020 HS5 830241    6 830241
# 8  2013 HS4 321590    6 321590
# 9  2010 HS3 010210    6 010210
# 10 2010 HS3 010210    6 010210
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2016, 2016, 2017, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2013, 2010, 2010), Pf = c("HS4", "HS4", "HS4", "HS5", "HS5", 
"HS5", "HS5", "HS4", "HS3", "HS3"), Code = c("391890", "440929", 
"851660", "732399", "720839", "050510", "830241", "321590", "010210", 
"010210"), Slen = c("6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: When argument = 'HS3', code must copy-paste value from Code to Code2. In your output, number of rows is 9, while I have 10 rows. Also in Code2 instead of <NA> there must be the same code (010210) as in the Code column. In addition, is it possible to keep original names? HS3 instead of HS3.9 and etc.

Comment: @user15330237 This should be no problem, I replaced the `else NA` with a copy of the code in `"HS3"` condition. And I removed the `unique` which deleted the duplicated row. Actually that's why I asked for the purpose of your `group_by` thing.

Comment: and can I keep original values like HS3 instead of HS3.9, HS3.10 etc.?

Comment: @user15330237 Those are just row names actually, I removed them.

Comment: is it possible to somehow avoid using apply() function in the code? because I have big data and it slows down the computation too much and need to wait hours.

Comment: @user15330237 Why do you think that `apply` is slow? Replace it with `Vectorize(concordance::concord)(x[, 'Code'], x[, 'Pf'], x[, 'Slen'], destination="HS3", all=FALSE)`, it's equally fast.

Comment: I don't know why or where is the root cause of the issue, but the process is still very slow. When I do it separately on df.H5 and df.H4 as indicated above into my code, process is super fast but when apply your code to the whole dataframe ...

Comment: @user15330237 You're right, I just benchmarked it, and I'm stunned. How does `Slen` change, it isn't always 6, is it? In each subset, would Slen be identical? And would you mind to answer me why you use `group_by`, your example also works without it. Thanks.

Comment: Slen is always 6. Lets drop group_by. Do you see any solution?

Comment: @user15330237 Thanks, then it's sufficient to only vectorize `Code` and it's equally fast as your solution. I think, the `group_by` exactly took account for identical Pf and Slen. We also only could use the first value `[1]` which is what I did. Please see update

Comment: Could you tell me what x$P means? is should be x$Pf or...?

Comment: @user15330237 Yes, indeed a typo. It still worked because of partial matching, read `?\`$\`` and `?names`.

Comment: Just one more question, could you explain what the last 2 line stands for? what do they do?: by(data, data$pfCode, cf) |>
  unsplit(data$pfCode)

Comment: @user15330237 The `by` splits the data into groups according to `Pf`, then applies the `cf()`function, finally un-splits it back according to the information stored in the `"by"` object.